# How can we create deadlock condition on our servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I think calling doGet() from doPost() and vice versa cause a deadlock?
 Or, does it cause a
StackOverflowException?
Or it just become a infinite loop?

Comment: you should try to see for yourself :-)

Comment: @J.Lucky What ya talking 'bout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think calling doGet() from doPost() and vice versa cause a deadlock?

No.

Servlets have no internal synchronization, unless you provide it, and calling a synchronized method from another synchronized method in the same thread cannot cause a deadlock anyway.

> Or, does it cause a StackOverflowException?

Not unless your `doGet()` method calls `doPost().`

> Or it just become a infinite loop?

No.

Comment: Then how can we create deadlock on our servlet?is there any answer u can suggest or more